# Showing the limit of a sequence of function exists a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, convolution, almost-everywhere

Given $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, define
$$T_n f(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} n^4 \exp\left(-n\sqrt{\left|y_1\right|+\left|y_2\right|} \right) f(x-y) dy$$
and I want to show that the limit exists for almost every $x$.

I feel like the limit should be something like $\langle \delta_x, f\rangle$ and some constant factor, since outside of any $B(0,\epsilon)$, $\lim_n T_n f(x)=0$. I tried to separate the integral
$$T_n f(x) = \frac{\pi}{\left|B\left(0,\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right|} \int_{B\left(0,\frac{1}{n^2}\right)} \exp(-n\sqrt{|y_1|+|y_2|}) f(x-y) dy \\+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2\setminus B\left(0,\frac{1}{n^2}\right)} n^4\exp\left(-n\sqrt{|y_1|+|y_2|}\right) f(x-y) dy $$
and I wanted to find a way to apply Lebesgue differential theorem. Could you give me some hints.

Comment: Using approximation of an integrable function by continuous functions with compact support and boundedness in $\mathbb L^1$ of the sequence of functions $\left(g_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ given by $g_n(y)=n^4\exp\left(-n\sqrt{\left|y_1\right|+\left|y_2\right|}\right)$, we get $\lVert T_nf-cf\rVert_1\to 0$, where $c:=\int_{\mathbb R^2}g_1(y)\mathrm dy$. This gives the existence of an almost everywhere convergent subsequence. Therefore, the only possible limit is $cf$, as you suggested. However, I do not know how to get the almost everywhere convergence. I'm not used with convolution. I think...

Comment: ... that the particular form of the kernel $g_n$ has to play a role somewhere.